# How to Navigate to the next page after closing an interstitial ad in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I want my ad to show every three clicks.
The first click should show an ad.
The next two clicks should not show any ad. and then the fourth should.
This process currently works fine, the only issue is that I want to navigate to the next page after the ad closes but currently, nothing happens when I close the ad. it just remains on the current page
So basically, the first click should show the ad and navigate to the next page when the interstitial ad is closed.
the second click should navigate alone.
the third click should navigate alone.
Then restart the process.

My code is below -

```
CategoryCardWithImage(
                            title: "networks",
                            image: "assets/images/networks.png",
                            press: () {
                              clickCount = clickCount + 1;
                              bool shouldDisplayAd =
                                  clickCount == 1 || clickCount % 3 == 0;
                              if (shouldDisplayAd) return _showInterstitialAd();
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                                  return NetworksPage();
                                }),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
```

Help fix code

Comment: Is it possible to move the Navigator inside the _showInterstitialAd()? because once  "shouldDisplayAd" is enabled, the return from "_showInterstitialAd()"  will stop the press() process.

Comment: @FredericChang how do I write the code? I've tried but can't seem to do it

Answer (score 1):

I use [AlertDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html)
to simulate what you would like to achieve.
You could add more if..else condition in the onPressed() function to know which page will be shown after selecting.

```dart
  void router() {
    var aaa = showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text('MyTitle'),
        content: Text('sdf'),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            child: Text('ok'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, creationCategory.id);
          },),
        ],
    ));
  }
```

```dart
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Record'),
        leading: null,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, creationCategory.id);
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
            onPressed: () async {
              router();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Fig1. Pushing that button to invoke void router()
Fig2. Popping Ad
Fig3. To close the Ad and then go to that specific pages.

[image: Pushing button]
[image: Pop Alertdialog(ad)]
[image: Pushing OK to another page]